# "Beautiful" or "beautifully"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Should I say *You look beautifully today* or *You look beautiful today*?

In my opinion, the first form is correct because *beautifully* describes the verb and not the noun. Thus, I should use the *beautiful* form in a sentence like *You are beautiful* when it describes the noun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Beautifully** is an adverb which describes a verb.
**Beautiful** is an adjective which describes a noun.

In your example, you're describing the "you", a noun, so **beautiful** is the one to use.

You're not describing the verb "looking" or the act of looking, so the adverb is not used.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that by beautifully I give the answer to the question: how(you look <- verb).  So in your opinion one should say: `You play beautifull on that piano?`

Comment: In the piano example, you're describing how they play, so use the adjective 'beautifully'.
In your example you're describing how they look, not the act of looking (seeing), so you use the adverb 'beautiful'.

Comment: @Yoda "you look beautifully" = "the way that you look at something is beautiful" just like "You play (the piano) beautifully" = "the way you play the piano is beautiful". You could say "you play beautiful music horribly" = the music is (supposed to be) beautiful, but you can't play it well

Comment: We are sure. These are called [*predicate complements* or *subject complements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement), and you should be able to find lots of information about them by Googling. One example of the difference between a predicate complement and an adverb is that *"he looks careful"* and *"he looks carefully"* mean completely different things. The first one means *"it appears to me that he is careful,"* while the second means *"he is searching carefully."*